# Help me with Linq query please

Tags: linq

I'm trying to get all the assets where Class property equals to one of the values in selectedIClassesList;

Something like this:

```
from x in Assets where selectedIClassesList.Contains(x.Class) select x
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to give us a little more context in your question.  Are you using LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, etc?  What does your Assets class look like? What does the type of Assets.Class look like? What does the IClassesList interface look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a join...

```
var query = from a in Assets
            join s in selectedClassesList on a.Class equals s
            select a;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Assets.Where(x=>selectedIClassesList.Contains(x.Class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, your problem is that IClassesList doesn't have a contains method? If IClassesList is an IEnumerable of the same type of object as x.Class, this should work.

```
from x in Assets where selectedIClassesList.Any(s => s == x.Class) select x
```

For better performance, you would do well to create a dictionary, though.

```
var selectedClassesDict = selectedIClassesList.ToDictionary(s => s);
var selectedAssets = from a in Assets 
                     where selectedClassesDict.ContainsKey(a.Class)
                     select a;
```

Comment: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.